# How do I add alias based on values of table

Tags: oracle, alias, oracle12c

As my title, for ex I have a table A and it has values from 1 to 10.

I want to Select value 1 and 2 as "First" column name, 3 and 4 as "Second" column name v.v.

Look like this:

```
|First| |Second|
   1       3
   2       4
   1       4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CASE`, perhaps?

```
SQL> with test as
  2    (select level val from dual
  3     connect by level <= 5
  4    )
  5  select case when val <= 2 then val end first,
  6         case when val  > 2 then val end second
  7  from test;

     FIRST     SECOND
---------- ----------
         1
         2
                    3
                    4
                    5

SQL>
```

It would help, though, if you provided sample data and explained what to do with values that aren't contained in (1, 2, 3, 4).